# Preloading images ios app

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have an app with 150 local images (about 500kb each). I have loaded them all into an array like this:

```
allPics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//NSString *imagePath;
NSArray *result = [database performQuery:@"SELECT image_path FROM validWords order by valid_word"];
for (NSArray *row in result) {
    NSString *temp = [row objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", temp);
    //imagePath = temp;
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:temp];

    [allPics addObject:newImage];
}
```

When I set my UIImageView later to one of these pics, it hangs my interface up for a second, due to lazy loading from what I have read. I tried to prerender them, but that spiked my memory usage to over 3gb before it got a third of the way through my images. Should I be looking to use a background thread to render the image when I need it? When I reduced the image total to 4, once all 4 were rendered once, the transitions between them was seamless.

I appreciate any and all tips and solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would suggest a background thread and paging. If the user is looking at image 7, you should load images, say, 5,6,8 and 9. If the user then moves onto image 8, you can discard image 5 and lazy load image 10. This way the user sjhould be able to move through your images without a significant memory or performance overhead.

You can then also add heuristics such as 'if the user is paging through the images very quickly, don't load any images until they slow down',

Another tip is to store a very low resolution version of the image (say, a 50kb version) and store that at a different path. Then you can show the thumbnail images to the user and only lazy load in the high res image if the user stops on that image for a period of time.

Finally, be careful when you talk about image sizes. Is the 500KB compressed or uncompressed? If it is a 500KB compressed JPeg, the actual image on the device could be vastly bigger. A jpg with fairly uniform colour and a reasonably high level of compression can be very small on disk, but decompressed it could be a massive image. This could be another source of the lag you experience.

Comment: 500kb on the disk, the resolution is 6000x6000. The images were done by a graphic artist, and I am scaling them down to about 400 x 400 on a non retina ipad. Is this scaling processes adding alot of overhead to the rendering?

Comment: WOW. ok, there is your problem right there. 6000x6000 is massive in memory. Imagine you are using 8 bits of information for red, green, blue and alpha channels. this means you have 6000x6000 pixels where each pixel takes up 4 bytes (commonly used size). that's 144000000 bytes of space needed to represent the image on disk before scaling. My advice, pre-scale the image to 400x400 before puttin it on the device. A good rule of thumb is to always pre-process if you can.

Comment: Depending on how you are handling the scaling, IOS will handle the scaling without loading the whole image into memory at once, but this is going to give you the overhead you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks! I will have my graphic artist make the changes to the image set.

Comment: Just wanted to update on this, I reduced them to 800x800 and its infinitely better. Thanks Bergasms!

Comment: You're welcome. You've taken your first step into the ongoing battle between design and implementation. And yeah, always remember, if you can get away with pre-processing then do it. Also processing once and storing the results for later is another tip, disk space is cheap, ram is not :) Happy coding.